# Django get all Models with an associated Model

Tags: django

Hi im currently trying to learn Django. How would I write a query to get all Person instances that have an associated existing Form instance. For example:

These are my models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Form(models.Model):
    filled_by = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have the following Person objects

- PersonA: {id: 1, name: 'Will'}
- PersonB: {id: 2, name: 'Greg'}
- PersonC: {id: 3 name: 'Dan'}

And the following Form objects

- Form1: {filled_by: PersonA}
- Form2: {filled_by: PersonC}

Query should return PersonA and PersonC

Answer (score 0):

Without doing any change to your models, you could do a query to filter the persons that have X `id` using the `filled_by_id` from every form you have;

```
Person.objects.filter(id__in=Form.objects.values_list("filled_by_id", flat=True))
```

Which would be something like this in SQL;

```
select *
from person
where person.id in (select filled_by_id from form)
```

You could also try an inner join query by using select_related, but you'll have to update `filled_by` in Form to tell what's the name of the relation to the Person model.

See [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [`ForeignKey.related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).